# How to install Percona Monitoring and Management in windows System

Tags: mysql, percona

I have MySQL installed in windows system. Now as I need to install Percona Monitoring and Management tool (https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/index.html) to track the MySQL but as per the documentation, They do not see to provide much support for the Windows.

I have also tried it with Docker but could not able to install PMM clinet.
Can you suggest me the way to run PMM in Windows?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Unfortunately this isn't programming related. You may have better luck at https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/936546/153161